# Argument data type int is invalid

Tags: sql

```
select OrderID,
    format(sum(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1 - Discount)), 2) as Subtotal
from tblOrderDetails
group by OrderID
order by OrderID
```

I got this error 'Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function.' after executing the code above.

[image: data type]

[image: result table]

Comment: What format do you want for the subtotal?

Comment: I want int for the subtotal

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to report the subtotal as an integer, use a plain cast:

```sql
SELECT OrderID,
       CAST(SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity * (1 - Discount)) AS int) AS Subtotal
FROM tblOrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderID
ORDER BY OrderID;
```